# csh - check if $PATH variable contains a substring

Tags: shell-script, shell, python, path, csh

Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, but I want to add Python to my `$PATH` variable if it isn't already in there.

Here's my code

```
# Add Python to $PATH
if(-e /path/to/python/bin && (! $PATH.Contains('python')) then
    set path=($path:/path/to/python/bin)
else
    echo 'ERROR: Unable to find the path to Python executable in .cshlc!'
endif
```

Comment: Many ways to do this, see [How to keep from duplicating path variable in csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135754/how-to-keep-from-duplicating-path-variable-in-csh)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick IDK, that solution is in PERL. I was hoping to not use another language to achieve a simple `if` statement

Comment: There are some csh-only answers there, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way, with a couple minor improvements:

```
if (-d /path/to/python/bin && "$path" !~ *"/path/to/python/bin"*) then
    set path=($path /path/to/python/bin)
else
    echo 'ERROR: Unable to find the path to Python executable in .cshlc!'
endif
```

I changed `-e` to `-d`, to be a slightly stronger test for a directory's existence, then I check to see if the `$path` variable contains anything like `/path/to/python/bin`; if the directory exists and the path variable does not yet contain that path, then append it. I believe csh syntax uses spaces to separate elements in the path, not colons.

Comment: Yes, csh use spaces to separate path elements in the variable `$path`, however, the variable `$PATH` use colons `:` (as is usual).